# ¿cómo cuento cuál es la secuencia más larga dentro de una lista de valores repetidos?

Tags: python, lista, revisión-de-código, metodología

```
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Es que tengo una lista como esta y necesito sacar cuál es la repetición más larga del número 1 en la secuencia.
En este caso, sería 4. 
Sé que es con ciclos.

```
 while i2<len(part_gan):
        if part_gan[i2]!=part_gan[(i2+1)]:
            mayor_racha+=1
        i2+=1
    return mayor_racha
```

Tengo esto pero, me da que *list index out of range*.
(part_gan es la lista de arriba).

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias pero, no entiendo muy bien cómo hacer este código estoy bastante confundida. Solo se me ocurre el ciclo que acabo de crear.

Comment: Antes de escribir código, sobretodo cuando lo que quieres hacer es complejo, es buena idea plantearse el procedimiento de cómo lo harías tú. Paso a paso. Si te ayuda puedes expresarte con diagramas de flujo u otras opciones. Una vez sabes cómo lo harás lo pasas a código y listo.

Comment: Es que no sé si en Python se pueden incrementar las variables así. Lo he intentado y me sale invalid sintax

Comment: Disculpa mí ignorancia, hace tiempo no toco Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que tener en cuenta una cosa muy importante, si en cada iteración indizas sobre `lista[i]` y `lista[i + 1]`, `i` no puede llegar a ser `len(lista) - 1` (`while i2 < len(part_gan)`).

Ésto se debe a que al hacer `lista[i + 1]` en la última iteración indizas con `lista[len(lista)]` y eso es un índice inválido. Realmente, como solo te interesan las secuencias de unos, puedes simplemente iterar sobre un elemento y considerar rota la secuencia cuando un item no sea 1.

Por otro lado, necesitas dos variables una que almacene el número de items de la secuencia más larga encontrada hasta ahora y otra para contar los items de la secuencia actual. Cuando la secuencia actual de unos se rompa miras si tu contador actual es mayor que el máximo y si lo es lo actualizas, luego reinicias el contador de tu secuencia actual y continuas iterando.

```
mayor_racha = 0
racha_actual = 0
for item in part_gan:
    if item != 1:
        if racha_actual > mayor_racha:
            mayor_racha = racha_actual
        racha_actual = 0
    else:
        racha_actual += 1
print(mayor_racha if mayor_racha > racha_actual else racha_actual)
```

Podemos usar `max()` para simplificar:

```
mayor_racha = 0
racha_actual = 0
for item in part_gan:
    if item != 1:
        mayor_racha = max((mayor_racha, racha_actual))
        racha_actual = 0
    else:
        racha_actual += 1
print(max((mayor_racha, racha_actual)))
```

Otra opción es usar `itertools.groupby` y obtener el máximo de la longitud de los grupos de unos:

```
from itertools import groupby

print(max(sum(1 for _ in grupo) for valor, grupo in groupby(part_gan) if valor))
```

Comment: Muchas, muchas gracias. Estaba estancada con este problema :) Y me ayudaste a solucionarlo. Gracias.